# Angular Injecting Multiple Dependencies Into Factory

Tags: angularjs

I need to inject the `$route` variable into the factory below in order to get the `GET` request to refresh. How would I inject it into the factory below?

```
.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
  //other factory functions

  o.factorySubmit = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/clients').then(function(){
        $route.refresh();
      });
  };

  return o;
}])
```

Comment: Same as you done for $http. Note that you are maintaining sequence. As they get mapped.

Comment: As soon as I add the `['$http', '$route', function($http, $route){` the application stops working

Comment: make sure that you have added 'ngRoute' as dependency to your module. for example, angular.module('yourModule', ['ngRoute'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got [Inline Array Notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) set up for your Dependency Annotation for your factory method.

Here's how you would inject $route:

```
.factory('posts', ['$http', '$route', function($http,$route){
  //other factory functions

  o.factorySubmit = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/clients').then(function(){
        $route.refresh();
      });
  };

  return o;
}])
```

Comment: Hmm.. that's what I started with.. didn't work. Do I need to declare the $route elsewhere outside of the factory? I am using ui.router for routing..

Comment: This is the correct way of injecting routes. You don't need to declare `$route` anywhere else. If your application is generating an error, or stops working once you add this, then there is probably some other configuration issue in your application. Have you properly added `ui.router` as a dependency for your module(s)?

Comment: Yeah, I have and it works. But as soon as I add any second dependency to a factory, I get: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: The `infdig` error that is thrown is the clue to the problem. Reference: [infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig). I would bet that if you comment out the `$route.refresh();` call that the error goes away, but it won't solve the issue. Since it sounds like you need to refresh the route upon successfully getting some information from the server, why not use an angular resolve for the route instead and get the information before going to that route? Reference: [ui-router resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: Also, this issue your bring up is a separate issue entirely, you may need to post a separate question to resolve this issue if you need further guidance on it.